# Javascript Profiling with Chrome Devtools

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, google-chrome-devtools, profiler

I am trying to profile some javascript code on [this url](https://www.priceline.com/m/fly/search/NYC-MAD-20220523/?cabin-class=ECO&no-date-search=false&num-adults=1&sbsroute=slice1&search-type=10&vrid=80b0eb7118d4bc1a0851c669dba4d13e) by setting an event listener breakpoint on mouse click.
When you click on any flight on the results page, it opens a new tab with another link and the logic to build that link must be using javascript, since there is no network traffic going on when the click is done.

The problem is when doing a profiling it shows some js functions called but none of them related to the new tab opened. Maybe it is related to some other event? Any other ways to profile this use case?

Basically the goal would be to understand how that new tab link is generated and get it without the need to actually click it, using data that must be already present somewhere on the code beforehand.

Any insights would be appreciated!

Comment: Try running `debug(window.open)` and then inspect the callstack upwards.

Comment: @wOxxOm you mean running that function on the console? Or somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/utilities/

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for the great tip! Unfortunately I'm seeing the js where the window.open is made but not where the link parameters are coming from. Seems like there is some react magic going on that is not visible in devtools.